# Error when calling method

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse, oop

Hey I am trying to call a method "swapPairs(int[] nums)", but I am getting multiple errors

```
 - Syntax error on token "{", delete this token
 - The method swapPairs(int[]) in the type ArrayMethods is not applicable 
  for the arguments (int, int, int, int)
- Syntax error on token "swapPairs", @ expected before this token
- Syntax error on token ";", @ expected after this token
- Syntax error on token "}", delete this token"
```

This is my code:

```
public class ArrayMethods {
   public static void main(String[]args){
        System.out.println(swapPairs({5,4,2,6}));
        allLess({5,4,3}, {4,7,5});
    }
    public boolean allLess(int[] nums, int[] num){
        int c=0;
        if(nums.length==num.length){
            for(int i=0; i<num.length; i++){
                if(nums[i]<num[i])
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;


    }
    public int[] swapPairs(int[] nums){
        int[] x=new int[nums.length];
        if(nums.length%2==0){
            for(int i=0; i<nums.length; i++)
                x[i]=nums[i+1];
            return x;
        }
        else
            for(int i=0; i<nums.length-1; i++)
                x[i]=nums[i+1];
        return x;

    }
    public void printArray(int[] nums){
        for(int i=0; i<nums.length; i++)
            System.out.println(nums[i]);
    }



}
```

In the method swapPairs I might also have an error. The goal of that is to swap adjacent elements in an array, and if the length of the array is odd then to keep the last element where it is. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't access `non-static` members from a `static` class.

```
System.out.println(swapPairs({5,4,2,6})); // swapPairs() is non-static
allLess({5,4,3}, {4,7,5}); //allLess() is non-static
```

Solution:

Make a instance of `ArrayMethods` to access the `swapPairs()` method and `allLess()` method or make these method `static`.

**But** there are more issues here. You can't use `swapPairs({5,4,2,6})` you have to use `swapPairs(new int[]{5,4,2,6})`

One corrected way

```
 ArrayMethods arrayMethods = new ArrayMethods();
 System.out.println(arrayMethods.swapPairs(new int[]{5, 4, 2, 6})); // *
 arrayMethods.allLess(new int[]{5, 4, 3},new int[]{4, 7, 5});
```

Pay attention to `*` line. You are calling `toString()` explicitly. This is not a good practice.

**More issues:**

```
  for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++)
    x[i] = nums[i + 1]; // you will get ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
     return x;
```

When `i=nums.length-1`, `nums[i + 1]` will become `num[nums.length]`. Now there is no such index in the array. If the size of the array is `4`, You have indexes from `0` to `3` only.

You can take these points to your account and make these mistakes correct.